# SPARQL how to get all triples with Individuals?

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, triples, stardog

I'm just getting started with SPARQL. I am not sure where the error is. I came across the error as I was testing out the reasoner.

i use Stardog as database and the reasoner is definitely on.

i have a simple model with two classes: Building and Room and with 1 individual each: building001 and room001.

I have two ObjectProperties hasLocation and isLocationOf .
Both ObjectProperties are inverse to each other.

The triple: Building001 hasLocation Room001 I have predefined, the reasoner should actually recognize the triple Room001 isLocationOf Building001 itself.

I now want to output all triples that belong to individuals. So I should get the two triples just described as a result.

With the query:

```
select * where {
       ?subject ?property ?object.
       ?subject a owl:NamedIndividual.
       ?property a owl:ObjectProperty.
       ?object a owl:NamedIndividual.
}
```

I only get the triple Building001 hasLocation Room001 as result.

with the query:

```
select * where {
       ?subject ?property ?object
}
```

I get the following triples as result :

```
Building001 hasLocation Room001
Room001 isLocationOf Building001
Building001 rdf:type Building
Building001 rdf:type owl:Thing
Room001 rdf:type Room
Room001 rdf:type owl:Thing
```

How do I get all the triples that belong to individuals? without getting rdf:type in the result?

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hi, can you provide us the exact data set you are querying?

Comment: `rdf:type` is not an `owl:ObjectProperty`, thus, your query is too restrictive then

Answer (score 0):

You can just filter out `rdf:type`:

```
SELECT * {
    ?s ?p ?o
    FILTER (?p != rdf:type)
}
```

You'll notice when you turn reasoning on the triples associated with your schema are not returned but the `rdf:type` triples are. That's because these triples are considered part of your individual assertions, not your schema.